# AVR Programming : Chip Enable Program Error

Tags: avr

I am working on avr controllers for a while, but I have problem with "progisp" avr programming software. When I buy a new micro-controller like atmega32 it can be programmed properly for a while but after some days, suddenly when I want to reprogram it, Progisp shows the error "Chip Enable Program Error". I use USB programmer. For better understanding here is an image of progisp software.

[image: progisp software error]

I have searched the internet a lot to find a solution but there wasn't a proper and useful solution for my problem. I am sure that my micro-controllers are fine and not damaged because they work as they programmed but I am unable to reprogram them.
I really thank you if you have any solution to help me.

And here is schematic diagram and real picture of my USB programmer.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Given that this will be a hardware issue, not a software issue, we will need a lot more information from you before we can help. e.g. schematic, pictures of hardware, what steps you have tried, etc.

Comment: What is your USB programmer? How does the wiring look like?

Comment: I have added schematic diagram and picture of USB programmer. i have searched the internet for a while, Someone said that you may accidentally programmed clock fuse bits as external clock or oscillator but it could be true because when i plug them without any external oscillator it works as it has been programmed.

Comment: I always program high fuse bits and low fuse bits as oxD9E4 and all lock bits all equal to 1 and that are disabled.

Comment: Did you happen to configure the reset pin as an input or an output?

Comment: So i am not sure, when i plug it in, the reset pin works as it has to be and the micro-controller tasks restarts, When i apply a GND voltage to it. So does it means that it is not set as I/O Pin?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a picture of one side of a PC board is not a schematic.

Comment: Because I actually couldn't find its exact schematic. I had no OTHER CHOICE.

Comment: There are a few possibilities to this particular issue specifically mentioned [here](https://eshop.eca.ir/%D8%B3%D8%A7%D8%AE%D8%AA-%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%86/489-%D9%BE%D8%B1%D9%88%DA%AF%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%B1-%D9%85%DB%8C%DA%A9%D8%B1%D9%88%DA%A9%D9%86%D8%AA%D8%B1%D9%84%D8%B1%D9%87%D8%A7%DB%8C-avr-%D9%85%D8%AF%D9%84-multi-avr-programmer.html). The machine translation from Iranian does not fill me with confidence so I'll let  you figure it out. If you find a solution you can write your own answer and select it.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error before when I changed the clock fuse bits and set at external RC Oscillator, maybe you have the same problem.
use a resistor and capacitor and build an external oscillator for your clock source and reprogram your micro.maybe it is work.

Comment: But you mean that you have set the fuse bits as external clock oscillator? If so i haven't do that. And as i said above they have been set as internal oscillator.